# VSCode will not Launch Raspberry Pi

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have downloaded the 32 bit ARM VScode to my raspberry Pi 3. It is currently running Jessie and I have ran updates and upgrade.

The VSCode icon is available and I can find the exe file is installed. When I click to open it will not launch. Nothing happens, no messages or dialog box. I have uninstalled and reinstalled and still the same thing happens.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, and this command worked for me:

```sh
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: I ran the suggested command and still does not run.  When I try to run code from the terminal I get a segmentation fault.